# foundation 6 tooltip position issue

Tags: tooltip, zurb-foundation

The problem is that tooltip is in wrong place - on far left side. So for instance when I hover element with tooltip that is on right side of the screen it will show tooltip on the left side far away from the hovered element. I could't find anything useful on the topic so far. Tried different options, but all tooltips were displayed on the left. Code for my tooltip copied from official foundation page

```
<button class="button has-tip" type="button" data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" 
data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" data-position="top"
title="Fancy word for a beetle." data-alignment="center">
      Top Center
</button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What version of Foundation are you using?  Here is a jsfiddle with your HTML using Foundation 6.4.1, and it works fine.  The only thing I changed was to add a margin on the button to allow the tooltip to position on top.  https://jsfiddle.net/genestd/svygwghz/

```
<div>
  <button class="button has-tip center" type="button" data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" data-position="top" title="Fancy word for a beetle." data-alignment="center">
  Top Center
  </button>
</div>
```

.

```
.center{
  margin: 100px;
}
```

Comment: ~ 6.3. Your solution did not work unfortunately. I haven't seen any issues on foundation or lib source page I am using (foundation-rails gem) any issues so I suppose I have sth overridden form tooltip classes.